# Delete all lines before n lines above the line containing the first match

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

If a file contains the following:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

How to delete the lines above two lines before "Line 5", so that the file will now contain only the following?

```
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

Comment: Can the file contains multiple `Line 5`s? What should happen if a `Line 5` occurred 3 lines before another `Line 5`? What should happen if the input contains `FooLine 597` - is that considered a match for `Line 5` or not? Can your real `Line 5` text actually contain regexp metachars and, if so, should they be treated as such or as literal?

Comment: @EdMorton 1) Yes. 2) As I've asked "the first match" will be will be considered to delete the lines before n lines above it. 3) Normally, "FooLine 597" will also be a match unless one uses "^Line 5$" as match pattern, and I think ideally the answer should support RegEx. Thanks for this; I'll check the first 4 answers below if RegEx match pattern works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with any [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { keep = 2 ; findRe = "Line 5" }

!f && $0 ~ findRe {
        for ( i = 1; i < NR; i++ )
                if ( ( i + keep ) >= NR ) print m[i]
        f++
}

!f { m[NR] = $0 ; next }

1
```

Save it in a file called, say, `exec.awk` and call it as: `awk -f exec.awk data`

You can edit the boundaries, and the match keyword, by editing `keep` and `findRe` variables.

Comment: Sorry for the poor quality of the question, which failed to show in the example that there might other instances of "Line 5" and some possible derivatives as well. This doesn't limit the operation with the first match, but goes on searching for other instances of match string, and oddly inserts 2 blank lines above them - no deletion, luckily.

Comment: So, if i understand well, the script should not repeat himself after the first match, but ( after the first match ) print anything it finds till the end. 
It should do a straight match on "Line 5" or match on derivates as well?

Comment: @Sadi see the edit

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected now. And it's also worth noting that `"Line 5"` defined in the script above can and should be modified as `"^Line 5$"` if one needs to skip partial matches like `"FooLine 5"`, `"Line 52"` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Such problems are easier to solve by first reversing the input line wise. For example:

```bash
$ tac ip.txt | awk '1; /Line 5/{n=3} n && !--n{exit}' | tac
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

`n && !--n{exit}` will become `true` when `n` reaches `0`. In this case, that means the line containing `Line 5` followed by two more lines.

With `sed`:

```bash
tac ip.txt | sed '/Line 5/{n; n; q}' | tac
```

**Note**: The above solutions won't work if there are multiple matches, as it would match the last occurrence in the file. Here's one workaround:

```bash
awk '!f && /Line 5/{print p2 ORS p1; f=1} f; {p2=p1; p1=$0}' ip.txt
```

Comment: This works well but with a minor deviation: the output has got all lines (except the two previous lines) deleted before the *last match*, and not the *first match*.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to edit the answer to mention that this won't work for multiple matches

Answer (score 3):

This may be simpler using `ed` - which supports address offsets:

```
printf '%s\n' '/Line 5/-2,$p' | ed -s file
```

or (modifying the file in place)

```
printf '%s\n' '1,/Line 5/-3d' 'wq' | ed -s file
```

Comment: And if one wants to rule out partial matches like "FooLine 5" or "Line 52", it seems the command should be: `printf '%s\n' '1,/^Line 5$/-3d' 'wq' | ed -s file`

Comment: @Sadi good point - I kinda assumed that `Line 5` would be replaced by the "real" regex

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will read the whole input file into memory at once and so YMMV if the input file is huge.

Comment: Having said that - several other answers also read the whole file into memory so maybe that's OK for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file with fewer than 10,000 lines you could use this

```
grep -B2 -A9999 'test test' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -M "(.*\n){2}.*Line 5(.*\n)*" file
```

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v var=2 '/Line 5/{n=NR; for(i=n-var;i<n;) print ar[i++]}
!n{ar[NR]=$0}n'
```

Comment: And if one wants to rule out partial matches like "FooLine 5" or "Line 52", it seems the command should be: `pcregrep -M "(.*\n){2}.*^Line 5\n" file`

Comment: Is it possible to use the `awk` command so that it will accept variables as well? E.g. `match="^Line 5$"` and `lines=2`, and then `awk ... $lines ... $match ... file` A file called `exec.awk` used in another answer might be giving an idea but it's beyond me to try and convert it to a one-liner, if possible at all...

Comment: @Sadi See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script). This should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk with a 2-pass approach to read just 1 line at a time into memory so it'll work no matter how large your input file is (but won't work for piped input as we can't open that twice):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ if (/Line 5/) {n=NR-3; nextfile}; next } FNR>n' file file
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

If the version of awk you're running doesn't support `nextfile` it'll still work but just run a bit slower than if it did support `nextfile`.

Comment: And if one wants to rule out partial matches like "FooLine 5" or "Line 52", it seems the command should be: awk 'NR==FNR{ if (/^Line 5$/) {n=NR-3; nextfile}; next } FNR>n' file file

Comment: That'd probably be OK but it depends if you really want to do a regexp or string match and whether you mean partial line or partial word or something else but if you want to rule out any kind of  false matches then edit your question to state that and update your sample input/output to include cases where false matches might occur. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information on string/regexp full/partial matching concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable guidance which I will certainly bear in mind, and will be more careful in the future, but I think I've already got good answers to my question, so I wouldn't like to complicate things at this stage by changing/improving the question, although it seems I prefer a full-line regex match like `awk '/^o\.b$/' file`, which can be further modified as needed, like `awk '/^.*o\.b.*$/' file` etc.

Comment: The `^.*` and `.*$` in `/^.*o\.b.*$/` are doing nothing useful as they match either everything or nothing. IMO, you'd be better off doing a full-line string match `$0 == "o.b"` instead of `/^o\.b$/` and a partial line string match `index($0,"p.b")` instead of `/^.*o\.b.*$/` as the matching "patterns" are more concise and robust when treated as strings than when treated as regexps but with regexp metachars escaped to be treated literally. If you NEEDED to do a regexp match THEN you could do so using `/.../` or `match()`.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave above was useless; in real life one would need to use regex match patterns like `/^o\.b$/'` or `/^[0-9]*.*\so\.b$/'` or `/^.*\so\.b\s.*[0-9]*$/'` etc. I guess. Thank you also for the other very valuable additional information.